# Moses server installation

Tags: moses

I have installed moses successfully, I have also install xmlrpc-c via 
sudo apt-get install libxmlrpc-core-c3 then I have built the moses via 
./bjam --with-xmlrpc-c=[/path/to/xmlrpc-c-config]. While doing these I have followed the instructions in http://www.statmt.org/moses/?n=Development.GetStarted. Up to that point, I guess everything was correct. From now, I need to connect to the machine where moses is installed, however I could not start the mosesserver. What should I do with the file in mosesdecoder/contrib/server/mosesserver.cpp. I think after the build an executable should be created in there , or am I going to compile it manually? Btw, this is the remote version: x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

"mosesserver" binary executable is located in mosesdecoder/bin directory after successful compilation.

It can be started in a similar fashion to moses, i.e.
/path/to/mosesserver -f /path/to/moses.ini

It will run a web server on port 8080 by default, expecting XML-RPC v2 protocol to communicate.

For building, make sure you have Boost libraries (+ devel package) installed at a location where they can be found (i.e. /lib or /usr/lib or lib64, depending on the system) or add the path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH if you compile them manually.